# ReactJS + NextJS - How to pass props from _app.js to page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I just switched from ReactJS to NextJS and I can't find how to pass props from _app.js to a page.

I'm trying to call a function in _app.js from a different page. In ReactJS it was straight forward, since you had to make your own Router, you could just pass props from App.js down to the pages. Now in NextJS I'm not explicitly calling the page, so I can't pass the props anywhere.

What is the way to do it in NextJS?

Comment: How did you circumvent the issue since March?

Answer (score 6):

`_app.js`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
const yourFunction(); // this is your function you created

return <Component {...pageProps} yourFunction ={yourFunction}/> // here you pass it as a prop
}
```

In `page.js`

```
default export function Page({yourFunction}) { // destructure the function 

yourFunction(); // use the function
}
```

Comment: What if we have several pages?

Comment: should we do a switch satement on `Component`?

Comment: No, I don't advice doing that. My suggestion is put all props you want inside of `Component`, but in the `page` take only the props you need from it.

Comment: Alright thanks! But unsure our trick will work anyways: in my Create React App, there were some hooks in App.js, I don't know if they are allowed in _app.js

Comment: Do you think I stand a chance to migrate this file to Next.js?

Comment: You're welcome! And it should work without any issues. And hooks are fine in `_app.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for redux

Cover `<Component/>` with redux `<Provider/>`

```
import { store } from "../redux/store/store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Provider>
    );
}
```